# If I ask $2N$ people a yes or no question, what's the probability $N$ say yes?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, beta-function

Suppose I ask $2N$ people a yes or no question. The answer are independent binomially distributed random variables. Each individual has his own probability of saying yes. When the $i$th responds, he says yes with probability $p_i$. Moreover,

$$\\p_1,p_2,...,p_{2n} \sim Uniform[0,1]$$

and are independently and identically distributed. What is the probability half of the responders say yes?

---

I know that

$$\int_0^1p dp$$

Is the probability of voting yes for some individual. I'm inclined to express the probability half of the responders say yes as,

$$\\\int_0^1\binom{2N}{N} p^{N}(1-p)^{N}dp.\\$$

But this seems to impose that $p=p_1,p_2,...,p_{2n}$, which doesn't need to be the case.

Comment: I suspect that this is actually quite tricky to answer after seeing a paper that covers this question (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022053181900223).

Comment: Have you had a look at the answer I provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am not entirely sure, but here what looks right to me.*

Conditioned on $p=(p_1,\dots,p_{2N})$, what you have is a random variable $X_p$ following a [Poisson Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) with parameters $2N$ and $p$. So what you want is the probability that your random variable $X$ equals $N$, which is
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X=N\} = \mathbb{E}\mathbf{1}_{\{X=N\}} = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{X=N\}}\mid p]]
= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}[X_p = N]]
$$
From the known expression (cf. Wikipedia article) of the pmf of a Poisson Binomial r.v., we have 
$$
\mathbb{P}[X_p = N] = \sum_{A\in F_N} \prod_{i\in A} p_i \prod_{j\in A^c} (1-p_j)
$$
so that, by linearity of expectation and independence of the $p_i$'s, 
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{X=N\} &= \sum_{A\in F_N}\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i\in A} p_i \prod_{j\in A^c} (1-p_j)\right]
= \sum_{A\in F_N} \prod_{i\in A} \mathbb{E}[p_i] \prod_{j\in A^c} \mathbb{E}[(1-p_j)]\\
&= \sum_{A\in F_N} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\lvert A\rvert}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\lvert A^c\rvert}
= \frac{\lvert F_N\rvert}{2^{2N}}\\
&= \boxed{\frac{1}{2^{2N}}\binom{2N}{N}}
\end{align}$$
(I followed the notation of Wikipedia, writing $F_k$ for the set of all subsets of $k$ integers that can be selected from $\{1,2,3,\dots,2N\}$).

Comment: This is really clever. It is also intuitive that $\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2N}{N}$ is decreasing in $N$ (i.e. the probability of an even split should decrease with more degrees of freedom).

Comment: Yes. I reckon that the fact that this matches the probability of a Binomial with parameters $2N$ and $1/2$ is not too surprising in hindsight, due to the uniform distribution and independence of the $p_i$'s which average things out.